What does "around the corner" mean in "which will print out a drink for them and bartenders will make around the corner"?
From Amazon bringing talent together at new AI pop-up space in San Francisco 1:17

Since this is a party, instead of ordering a drink at the bar, people
are lined up to plug in what they’d like to drink and ingredients to
this generative AI mixologist, which will print out a drink for them
and bartenders will make around the corner.

Does it mean "going to happen soon" or someplace?

When used literally, "around the corner" means, a place that you get to by going a short distance and then turning right and perhaps going a short distance. (Right because Americans drive on the right side of the road, so turning right you stay on the same side of the street. If you had to turn left, it would be "across the street" rather than "around the corner".)
We only say "around the corner" when the distance to the turn is short. If it was 20 miles, you wouldn't say "around the corner". So people often say "around the corner" to mean "near". Like, "Bob lives around the corner from me." Could mean literally, I just have to travel a short distance and turn right to get to his house. Or could mean figuratively, he lives close to me.
From there, we often use "around the corner" to mean "close in time". Like, "An economic recovery is around the corner", meaning it's coming soon.
In this case, it's probably literal, though not talking about streets but about the layout in the place where the party is. You place your drink order, then you walk around the corner of the bar to get your drink.

Thanks, very nice.
